# Public network access on Azure batch to be enabled

Tags: azure-batch

I have a Azure Batch which by mistake i made  "Public network access" as denied. Is there a way to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new Batch account with public network access enabled. Please see the [private Batch account documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/private-connectivity). If you mistakenly created that Batch account, you can delete it.

Comment: Created a new batch account. Thanks